# Will it harm my 9v rechargeable battery if the +ve and -ve terminals are connected to each other

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, power-electronics, battery-chemistry

By mistake, the positive and negative terminal of a 9v rechargeable battery were connected to each other by me, and when I noticed it, I quickly removed it and the battery became hot a little. Did it caused any harm to my battery, Or should I use the battery or is it damaged now? Will it explode if I put it to charging now?

[Link to battery](https://www.amazon.in/-/hi/Uniross-210-%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%9A%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%9C%E0%A5%87%E0%A4%AC%E0%A4%B2-%E0%A4%AC%E0%A5%88%E0%A4%9F%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%80-%E0%A4%B8%E0%A4%AB%E0%A4%BC%E0%A5%87%E0%A4%A6/dp/B00E8G4KR6/)

Comment: This depends on the specific type of battery, which you haven't told us.

Comment: Battery type? Brand? Model?

Comment: https://www.amazon.in/-/hi/Uniross-210-%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%9A%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%9C%E0%A5%87%E0%A4%AC%E0%A4%B2-%E0%A4%AC%E0%A5%88%E0%A4%9F%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%80-%E0%A4%B8%E0%A4%AB%E0%A4%BC%E0%A5%87%E0%A4%A6/dp/B00E8G4KR6/ref=sr_1_5?crid=1F4OHL0TKXAVQ&dchild=1&keywords=uniross+rechargeable+batteries&qid=1604041666&sprefix=uniros%2Caps%2C2175&sr=8-5

Comment: why are you asking here? ... you asked at https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/78957/will-it-harm-my-battery-if-the-ve-and-ve-terminals-are-connected-to-each-other

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will a battery short out when the terminals are directly connected together or will internal resistance save it?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/322208/will-a-battery-short-out-when-the-terminals-are-directly-connected-together-or-w)

Comment: @jsotola This is the correct site to ask on - the Arduino site is not. I'll suggest to the Arduino admin that the other one be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

**Although one cannot be certain when treating a battery to such abuse**, it is likely that the battery will be safe to charge and to use.

The Uniross 210 rechargeable battery has NiMH (Nickel metal Hydride) chemistry.

Shorting the battery is a very bad idea and it may have damaged it somewhat but if the short circuit was not of long duration (seconds rather than minutes) the damage may not be too severe.

I have occasionally accidentally shorted NiMH AA cells for short periods in the past with substantial overheating. These have far higher discharge currents compared to the 9V battery and they were still usable after this treatment.

Comment: What is the conclusion from this whole paragraph, my battery was hot after that action, I think it was at least for 1 min, what should I do. How can I see is my battery good or not ??

Comment: @AmitNikhade The conclusion re safety and ability to use is in the first sentence.  |  The conclusion re damage is at the end of the 3rd sentence. | Testing capacity and recording lifetime is the way to check how much damage was done. || USE the battery. Charge it somewhere safe. It will PROBABLY work well enough. || For interest - where are you located? - I note the web links is to amazon.in

Comment: but the battery is working pretty well